# How to parse a csv file as a parameter for a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a python script which originally accepted a single URL as a parameter to the script, but now I'm looking to update the code to accept a CSV file as a parameter

Originally the script was executed using the following command:

```
python3 script.py -x -y www.example.com
```

The issue is that now I no longer have just one URL but a CSV file of 10'000 URLs.

How can I parse the URLs in the CSV file with commands in the terminal?

Comment: Accept your file as a single parameter and then create a method to read the file and execute your logic against each value in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your program the way it is, but instead of accepting a single URL at the command line, accept the name of a CSV file and then open up your CSV file and process each URL within the script

```
import sys
import csv
import requests


def get_next(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file, newline='') as csvfile:
        url_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in url_reader:
            for url in row[0].split(','):
                print(url)
                yield url


def process_url(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_csv_file = sys.argv[3]

    for url in get_next(url_csv_file):
        process_url(url)

>> http://www.google.com
>> <Response [200]>
>> http://www.facebook.com
>> <Response [200]>
>> http://wikipedia.com
>> <Response [200]>
```

The command used to start the script:

```
python3 script.py -x -y mydata.csv
```

This was the contents of the CSV file used as input:

```
http://www.google.com,http://www.facebook.com
http://wikipedia.com
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. I've already implemented this feature in the past , but now I am testing multiple scripts on this URL-list and would like to use them without the need to edit them all.

Comment: Are you planning to take 10000 CSV URLs as a single parameter to your script? i.e python3 script.py -x -y www.example.com,www.facebook.com,www.wikipedia.com,www.stackoverflow.com,www.reddit.com,...etc ?

Comment: I was hoping to use the csv filename and a method to extract row by row with a for-loop and passing it as a parameter to script.py

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do. Your question asks for a solution which accepts a CSV file with 10k rows, and this solution works for that, but then you say you already had this inplace and want something different to 'use the CSV file name and a method to extract row by row and a for loop'..? Is that not what you already have? And what's in this answer?

Comment: You need to provide an example of your expected input, the current 'input' in your question is the old input, you should provide an expected input for your new script so we can understand what you're trying to do